# How do I execute code only when the text changes in a TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I have a text field for searching items in an array, and I am using a model, that has a published text property, bound to the field to call the search function every time the text changes.

My current issue is that every time anything happens with the text field, it sends a notification that is has changed, therefore the first time it appears it sends one, every time it is focused, defocused, or a letter was typed it sends two.

This shows how many times the field sends changes:

[image: Animation]

This is a simplified example of the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    @FocusState var focused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Field", text: $model.text)
                .submitLabel(.search)
                .focused($focused)

            Text("Field has sent changes \(model.textChanged) times")
            Button(action: { focused = false }) {
                Text("Defocus")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
    @Published var textChanged: Int = 0

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        $text
            .sink { text in
                self.textChanged += 1 // This is where i am doing my search call in the actual code
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

I have tried using `.onReceive` on the `TextField`, and `.onChange($text)` on the view instead of `.sink`, but that didn't change anything. I know that this is the default behaviour of `TextField`, but I would like to only execute the search, when the text has changed and not every time something happens with the field. Putting the search call in a `didSet` on the `text` property is also not an option.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you should never use ObservedObject where you own the object -- it should be `StateObject`

Comment: There should be no object at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just attach `.onChange` to the `TextField` (or you can attach it to any part of the `body` in fact).

You said you tried this before, but you used a binding. It shouldn't be a binding:

```swift
@State private var counter = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Field", text: $model.text)
            .submitLabel(.search)
            .focused($focused)
            // pre iOS 17: .onChange(of: model.text) { newVal in
            .onChange(of: model.text) { oldVal, newVal in
                counter += 1
            }

        Text("Field has sent changes \(model.textChanged) times, counter=\(counter)")
        Button(action: { focused = false }) {
            Text("Defocus")
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your model structure, then with minimal change to your code I'd suggest to use `removeDuplicates()`. The updated code to your Model will be:

```swift
import Combine

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
    @Published var textChanged: Int = 0

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        $text
            .removeDuplicates() // Just this line is added
            .sink { text in
                print("Text: \(text)")
                self.textChanged += 1 // This is where i am doing my search call in the actual code
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Please note that the first change you get in this `sink` is because you are assigning an empty string to the `text` in your model.